# Solution to ODE using power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question asks to find relation of the coefficients of the series solution around x=0 for the equation $y'''+x^2y'+xy=0$

Therefore trying:
$$y=\sum_{m=0}^\infty y_mx^m$$
$$\therefore y'=\sum_{m=1}^\infty my_mx^{m-1}$$
$$\therefore y''=\sum_{m=2}^\infty m(m-1)y_mx^{m-2}$$
$$\therefore y'''=\sum_{m=3}^\infty m(m-1)(m-2)y_mx^{m-3}$$
Subbing this back in gives:
$$\sum_{m=3}^\infty m(m-1)(m-2)y_mx^{m-3}+x^2\sum_{m=1}^\infty my_mx^{m-1}+x\sum_{m=0}^\infty y_mx^m=0$$

Fixing $y'''$:
$$\sum_{m=3}^\infty m(m-1)(m-2)y_mx^{m-3}=\sum_{m=2}^\infty (m+1)(m+2)(m+3)y_{m+3}x^{m}+6y_3+24xy_4$$
$y'$:
$$x^2\sum_{m=1}^\infty my_mx^{m-1}=\sum_{m=2}^\infty (m-1)y_{m-1}x^m$$
$y$:
$$x\sum_{m=0}^\infty y_mx^m=\sum_{m=2}^\infty y_{m-1}x^m+xy_0$$

Therefore combining these terms give:
$$\sum_{m=2}^\infty\left[(m+1)(m+2)(m+3)y_{m+3}+(m-1)y_{m-1}+y_{m-1}\right]x^m+6y_3+xy_0+24xy_4=0$$

However I am kind of unsure of how to continue this, so I was wandering if this was correct? If so I have the two equations, with one of them being:

$$6y_3+xy_0+24xy_4=0$$

I am not sure how I can deal with this equation to find the answer, help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your intermediate calculations are correct, for
$$\sum_{m=2}^\infty\left[(m+1)(m+2)(m+3)y_{m+3}+(m-1)y_{m-1}+y_{m-1}\right]x^m+6y_3+xy_0+24xy_4=0$$
to hold for all $x$, you need
$$
(m+1)(m+2)(m+3)y_{m+3}+(m-1)y_{m-1}+y_{m-1}=0
$$
[is the last subscript correct? double check...]
as well as $y_3=0$ and $y_0+24y_4=0$.

Solve for $y_{m+3}$ in terms of the previous $y_m$ and use $y_3=0$ and $y_4=-{1\over 24}y_0$ to aid in solving the recursion.